# Can't install via pip with Virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

Below is the error I get when I run `pip`:

```
serkan$ rm -r mysite
serkan$ pwd
/Users/serkan/Desktop/Python Folder
serkan$ virtualenv mysite 
New python executable in mysite/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
serkan$ source mysite/bin/activate
(mysite)serkan$ pip install pinax
-bash: /Users/serkan/Desktop/Python Folder/mysite/bin/pip: "/Users/serkan/Desktop/Python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ python pip install pinax
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ python pip install Pinax
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ python pip install Pinax
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ python pip install Pinax
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ python pip 
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ pip
-bash: /Users/serkan/Desktop/Python Folder/mysite/bin/pip: "/Users/serkan/Desktop/Python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$ pip install Pinax
-bash: /Users/serkan/Desktop/Python Folder/mysite/bin/pip: "/Users/serkan/Desktop/Python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
(mysite)serkan$
```

Comment: Try running it as `py -m pip install`, it works for me

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Create your virtualenv environment within a path without spaces. This is why it is happening:

When you create an environment, it sets up a `bin` directory. In that `bin` directory are all the executables relating to the environment. Some are scripts. As you may know, hashbangs are used to tell the system what interpreter to use to run the script. You may see this at the top of scripts often:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If the script is at `/tmp/test.py`, that tells the system to run this command to execute the script:

```
/usr/bin/env python /tmp/test.py
```

In your case, virtualenv is creating scripts like this:

```
#!/tmp/oh no/bin/python
```

When the system tries to execute that, it will try to execute the command `/tmp/oh` with the arguments `no/bin/python` and `/tmp/test.py`. `/tmp/oh` does not exist, so it fails.

Comment: I had the same error but no spaces, turns out what bit me is that you cannot move a virtualenv once created (which is utter madness…).

Comment: @alper: It [kind of supports](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#making-environments-relocatable) moving them around.

Comment: Thanks, this explained everything for me!  I guess this means you can't set up virtualenvs inside your Google Drive folder.

Comment: @GChorn: It would be a bit of a hack, but you could set up a symbolic link in a path without spaces to the Google Drive folder.

Comment: @icktoofay, thanks for the suggestion.  It's a small hack so I may go ahead and use it for the convenience of backing up my projects automatically.

Comment: @GChorn symlink didn't work with iCloud (/Mobile documents/) :(

Comment: I am getting the same error but I don't have spaces in my path and I did not move the venv. Edit: fixed as per @Hedde van der Heide's answer, shortening the path to the venv. It was very long.

Comment: In my case, the path that was holding the virtualenv had spaces, so I fixed renaming the folder which had spaces in its name.

Comment: "Create your virtualenv environment within a path without spaces." 

Very very trivial but important point explained... I would have never worried to check if this was a "space in the path" issue. 
Saved me so much time and frustration...

Answer (score 22):

`pip` command won't work if:

- **You have not installed pip in your system.** (you have to install pip first in your system before you can use it in virtualenv. To install `pip` on Ubuntu, use command `sudo apt-get install python-pip` or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`)
- **The path to your virtual environment folder contains space(s)**.*(Example: /home/username/my folder name with spaces/newvirtualenv)*
- **The path to your virtual environment folder is too long.** *Example: /home/username/mytoobigpath/somefolder/anotherfolder/someanotherfolder/someanotherfolderagain/myvirtualenv.* (Try renaming parent folders with smaller names)

If you can't rename folders or change path for some reason, goto `yourvirtualenvfolder/bin` (using `cd` command) and then try `./python pip install packagename`.

Comment: You're a hero.  It's kind of ridiculous that pip can't handle spaces AND doesn't specifically throw that error.

Comment: Ran into a long path issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know the `virtualenv` length limit?

Comment: Also ran into a length limit due to Jenkins workspace names. Character limit seemed to be 79 characters. CentOS7 AWS-hosted VM with kernel version 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64

Comment: I have to replace `python pip install packagename` with `./python pip install packagename` or it will end up using system python not the one in the virtualenv. I can't edit the answer because the edit is less than 6 characters.

Comment: @kkpattern If I got it right, it is the case you can't change or rename the virtualenv folder. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 21):

For those running into this issue, I discovered that the length of the path could cause issues as well, without using any spaces (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
virtualenv /home/user/some/very/longer/path/without/spaces/etc/venv
```

failed, while

```
virtualenv /home/user/some/very/long/path/without/spaces/etc/venv
```

worked just fine, see Alex's comment below

Comment: This isn't a bash constraint and in fact has nothing to do with the shells:  it's a kernel constraint in the exec call on the length allowed to specify the interpreter (and args) following the "#!" magic number.   Historically it was about 30 characters in older Unixen, in Linux it's closer to 80.

Comment: :-)   Now if we can just get people to Stop Putting .sh On Command Names.  It's soooo wrong for so many reasons.

Comment: Just to clarify, the kernel constraint is BINPRM_BUF_SIZE and the limit length is 127 bytes. More info: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#length

Answer (score 14):

icktoofay is correct about the cause.

To use pip with virtualenv in a directory with spaces, edit `/path/to/env/bin/pip`, replacing the shebang at the top with `#!/usr/bin/env python` (or `#!/usr/bin/env pypy` if you're using pypy).

Note that virtualenv changes your environment such that `/usr/bin/env python` refers to the `python` defined by the virtualenv.

Comment: @icktoofay, virtualenv changes the `PATH` defined by `env`. Thus, `/usr/bin/env python` will refer to the `python` defined by the virtualenv.

Comment: You're right. That seems obvious now, but I missed that for some reason.

Comment: No worries. I've changed my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! Somewhere along a project setup process, I was told to change the folders' names, but I had already created the virtualenv. It was now no longer allowing me to use pip to install packages. Editing the bin/pip executable and fixing the path to the new name did the trick! :)

Answer (score 3):

On Python 3.7 I didn't have any issues with this but when I had to use Python 3.6 I did have an issue. The most easy work-around I found on Github was this:

Instead of:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I use:

```
python env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So you actually directly point to the pip file within your virtual environment directory. Of course you need to activate it first before trying this. Hope this helps someone who comes here!

Comment: I don't know why it works, but it's the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in `RedHat`. Python 2.7.3 is configured and made by myself.

```
[root@Ifx installer]# pip install Django
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Solution: In `/usr/local/bin/pip`, replace first line `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7` with your actual Python path  `#!/root/installer/Python-2.7.5/python`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on my **Windows 7** machine and struggled couple of days with that. Both paths, to my python distribution and to my VE **had spaces** in it. Couple of months before it worked fine. I found the following note on virtualenv website:

```
**Windows Notes**
[...] To create a virtualenv under a path with spaces in it on Windows, you’ll need the win32api library installed.
```

The following steps lead me to success:

1. Make sure I used pip to install virtualenv and it's the latest version (pip-7.1.0). Result: **failure**.
2. Install win32api. Result: **failure** (although there was some error at the very end of installation process).
3. Try to install my VE in a path without spaces. Result: **failure**.
4. Reinstall my Anaconda python distribution to the path that didn't contain the "[" and "]" brackets. VE had spaces in the path. Result: **failure**.
5. Reinstall my Anaconda python distribution to the path that also didn't contain any spaces. The VE folder still had spaces in the path. Result: **success!**

So at least the Anaconda (python) installation simple, **non space-pollutted path was crucial**. Maybe win32api installation was also important. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from a Google search while experiencing the same problem and found this to be very useful.  `virtualenv` now has a `--relocatable` flag that will rewrite the shebang command to `#!/usr/bin/env <the_python_version_you_used_to_create_the_virtualenv>`.  It does come with some caveats, so be sure to read the documentation to understand the implications:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable

You need to use the same syntax to relocate the virtualenv as you did when creating it, otherwise the python version may be overwritten. This will work as expected...

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 env-test
virtualenv --relocatable --python=python3.5 env-test
```

whereas this will result in `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` (at least on my local environment)...

```
virtualenv --python==python3.5 env-test
virtualenv --relocatable env-test
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For my case, deactivate the environment and `source bin/activate` again works.

It seems my folder content has same subfolder names as generated by `virtualenv`, such as bin, lib etc. And after copy in my files, reactivate the environment let `virtualenv` to update new information.

Answer (score -1):

If it's on windows, it can be caused due to dll changes(by other software)
Installing openSSL would fix it.
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

It will automatically renew dll to its newer versions.

Comment: Error clearly shows it's due to error in hashbang (it's been resolved). Please read thoroughly before posting a quick answer.