# Using virtualenv with spaces in a path

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip

I set up a virtualenv environment on my Mac, but cannot get Pip to install packages. It fails with the following error:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tracked the problem down to there being a space in the path, as is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10873611/126564
(the path being `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Python/my_project`)

But that's a bit of a problem. The proposed solution is to:

> "just put your virtualenv environment in a path without a space,"

but *the part with the space is the volume itself.* All of my paths would have a space, unless I stored them in a directory of `/`. And I don't think "store your stuff outside of user space" is a good solution.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Better solution - contribute a fix to virtualenv?

Comment: It is an open issue at virtualenv project: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53

Comment: Manually escaping the paths in ./bin seems to work, so I left a comment to that effect in the issue tracker. I don't know if I want to try to contribute a fix or not, since I'm a bit of a Python newb.

Comment: I had similar issue on my Windows when trying to get my program to run via windows + r. it kept giving me errno2 no such path or directory so needles to say I got fustrated trying to figure out how to make the shebang work with white spaces and just made a new project_folder for my programs directly on C:. The strange thing is that somehow pip works in cmd for getting modules even though my main folder for Python is within a path that has a folder with white spaces.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Trying this:

- editing `bin/activate`, change `VIRTUAL_ENV='/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Python/my_project'`, and change `PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"`, to make it work in your environment. using `echo $PATH` to check if it works.
- editing `bin/pip` and `bin/easy_install`, change first line in the two files to

  `#!/usr/bin/env python`

After above 2 steps, you'll make your virtualenv works(also pip/easy_install).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I was poking around the files, but didn't think to edit the pip and easy_install ones. I just inserted a backslash before the space and it seems to be working so far.

Comment: After doing the above fixes, now my virtualenv is pointing to the wrong installation of python as specified by `virtualenv -p`

Comment: You can also use `sed -i '/^#!/ s@".*/\([^/]\+\)"@/usr/bin/env \1@' env/bin/*`

Comment: This question likely fixes the problem, but I frankly don't understand the instructions. Change PATH to *what*? Why?

Comment: @NicolasBouliane Change it such that it works, obviously.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking that question if I knew what to change it to.

Comment: @NicolasBouliane add a backslash before the space. So in this case, just change `VIRTUAL_ENV='/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Python/my_project'` to `VIRTUAL_ENV='/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Python/my_project'`.

Answer (score 18):

Note that you don't have to use your project folder for virtualenv. For example, you can place your virtualenv into **/tmp** folder or any other folder without spaces:

```
virtualenv /tmp/temporary_virtualenv
virtualenv /home/my_envs/env_for_projectname
```

Answer (score 11):

I have yet another workaround - you just need to use `pip` *package* instead of `pip` *script*. For example:

```
python -m pip install .
```

or even:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

For me works like a charm and doesn't require changes in files.

Answer (score 5):

Editing the `bin/activate` file and escaping the spaces worked for me.
Edit and save the file, then run `source bin/activate`.

Comment: You just have to put the \ before the spaces or parenthesis (e.g.: /Users/Name/Dropbox\ \(Personal \)/)

Comment: that didn't seem to work, maybe there's more than one file to edit? the answer would be better with a list

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have an atypical drive setup on your Mac, the path `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` should be a symlink to `/`. In other words, instead of

```
$ virtualenv /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/venvpath
```

you can just do

```
$ virtualenv /venvpath
```

Not that I'm trying to condone software not handling spaces in file names. I agree with [Hugo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472430/using-virtualenv-with-spaces-in-a-path#comment21918220_15472430) above: keep an eye on the [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53).

Answer (score 3):

As of end of 2018 the latest versions of `pip` and `virtualenv` deal with spaces in venv dir correctly.

See https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53#issuecomment-434461292 .