# How to activate conda env with space in its name

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

`conda env list` or `conda info -e` shows

`py35 python=3.5` as one of the environment.

How to activate conda env which has space in its name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using virtualenv with spaces in a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472430/using-virtualenv-with-spaces-in-a-path)

Comment: Where is the space? `py35` appears to be the name

Comment: @JossieCalderon This is specific to conda and not python virtualenv

Comment: @cricket_007 the env is in folder `py35 python=3.5` and `activate py35` doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to quote the environment name or create one without spaces or rename that one?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have since created a new conda env with only `py35` and have been using it. But need to find a way to remove or use in any fashion. Quoting doesn't seem to solve.

Comment: `py35` is the environment name and `python=3.5` is the version. You cannot create an environment with space in name. You should be able to activate it using `activate py35`. If it doesn't work, there is a problem with your environment.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr **Surround the environment name with DOUBLE quotes.**

@centau you can most definitely create environments with spaces in the name.

Duplicating the problem:

```
conda create -n "foo bar" python=3.5
```

Then inspecting the environments:

```
conda info -e
```

produces:

```
# conda environments:
#
foo bar                  C:\Users\edill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\foo bar
root                  *  C:\Users\edill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3
```

So you can see that there is an environment with the name "foo bar"

Then to activate it:

```
activate "foo bar"
```

Which modifies the command line to show:

```
(foo bar) C:\Users\edill>
```

So at this point I am reasonably confident that all is working properly with a space in the environment name, but let's just double check to make sure.  Check the file that one of the built in modules is coming from:

```
(foo bar) C:\Users\edill>python -c "import os; print(os.__file__)"
```

Shows that this built in `os` module is indeed coming from the `foo bar` environment

```
C:\Users\edill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\foo bar\lib\os.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution while trying to install conda environment in my Windows.

I have a space in one of my directory's name between My and MS.

> C:\Users\My MS\python\project_1\env

So I put " " to encase the whole directory to activate the environment:

> $ conda activate "C:\Users\My MS\python\project_1\env"

Answer (score -1):

Enter the name of the environment in double quotes.

e.g. when I activate my environment named - deep learning I use following command:

```
conda activate "deep learning"
```