# python virtualenv path with spaces issues on ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, bash, path, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv

I started a python virtual environment in the folder `/media/suraj/Extra Drive 1/testEnv/`. Notice the space in the path. Now everything works fine except when I use pip freeze.

```
(testEnv) bin > pip freeze
bash: /media/suraj/Extra Drive 1/testEnv/bin/pip: "/media/suraj/Extra: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So, I fix the environment variable in activate source file `VIRTUAL_ENV="/media/suraj/Extra Drive 1/testEnv"` to `VIRTUAL_ENV="/media/suraj/Extra\ Drive\ 1/testEnv"`. Now, after reactivating the environment I check `which python` but it points to the global python binary. I check if the PATH variable has the environment directory as the first directory and it does.

```
(testEnv) Extra Drive 1 > echo $PATH
/media/suraj/Extra\ Drive\ 1/testEnv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/suraj/.config/composer/vendor/bin/:/usr/local/aws/bin
```

So, I change the VIRTUAL_ENV to the original path without escaped space. Now things work fine but pip freeze doesn't work. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to put spaces in your directory name ? you'll only have problems.

Comment: Unfortunate my external drive has been named that way. Is there a way to rename it permanently without any risk?

Comment: Given the stupid name, I would say you can do it (you can still rollback to the previous name if you have too many problems).

Comment: see [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472430/using-virtualenv-with-spaces-in-a-path)

Comment: thanks, that works!!