# Error creating virtual environment for Flask app in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, flask

I get an "unexpected error" when creating a flash web app in visual studio. I get the following output:

```
Virtual environment is being created at 'c:\users\john dinh\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\potofolio2\potofolio2\env'
Using base prefix 'C:\\Users\\John Dinh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32'
New python executable in env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command "c:\users\john dinh\d...v\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  The repository located at None is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host None'.
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
    exec(code, run_globals)
No matching distribution found for setuptools
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
    main()
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "C:\Users\John Dinh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command "c:\users\john dinh\d...v\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
Virtual environment was not created at 'c:\users\john dinh\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\potofolio2\potofolio2\env'. Exit code: 1
```

I am on windows 10.

Comment: What `Python` version are you running for your environment? Or what is the default specified in your path environment variable?

Comment: the python version is 3.5

Comment: Virtualenv doesn't like Python when it has spaces in its installation path. I reinstalled mine in the classical C:\Python35 location and that fixed the issue. See this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911058/4573362).