# Why I can't install the dependencies for the Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the tutorial for creating a microblog using the Flask from the `Miguel Grinberg` website. The link is as following:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

After creating the microblog folder and entering inside, I created the virtualenv using the command `virtualenv flask`. This creates a `flask` folder inside the `microblog'. However, after I can't execute any of the following commands, say:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask
```

It will return the error:

```
bash: flask/bin/pip: "/Users/Chaklader/Documents/Online: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.
```

Should I enter the `flask/bin` folder and execute the commands ?

Note: I haven't activated the virtual environment using the command: `source flask/bin/activate` as suggested. I use Mac OS for working.

Here is the screenshot which is requested in the comment and it still returns error:

[image]

Comment: Why haven't you activated the virtualenv? Isn't that how one is supposed to use the pip inside the virtualenv?

Comment: It was suggested not to activate the virtualenv. However, I activated and it still doesn't work

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv

Comment: What's your error when you activated the virtualenv?

Comment: I still get the same error after activating the virtualenv

Comment: try renaming your enviromnement something other than "flask" this is quite likely to cause a clash with the module "flask" you're trying to install.

Comment: Still the same error here. Interesting issue

Comment: Did you get any error when activating the virtualenv? If not, just run `pip install flask`.

Comment: There was no error and I just ran the command   `pip install flask`  than `flask/bin/pip install flask` and still gets the same error. On the other hand, when I just open a new terminal and run   `pip install flask` it shows the requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Can you try three following steps: 1. `virtualenv venv`, 2. `source venv/bin/activate`, 3. `pip install flask`. If there's any error, could you paste the entire shell screen output from the step 1?

Comment: @dvnguyen  Yes and the error is posted as the screenshot inside the question.

Comment: Your whole filepath has **spaces**. The comment with the links above is correct

Comment: Thanks. Another guess is the white space in directory names might be the problem. Could you try it again in another working directory that doesn't have white space in its path. For example: `~/flasktutorial`.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. After I changed the folder name to without space, the whole issue is solved.