# gcloud ML engine setup - can't install pip "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up the environment for gcloud ML engine following the instructions here for MACOS and Python 2.7:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/command-line

When I get to steps 5-6 to install TensorFlow, I get:

bad interpreter: No such file or directory

That's even if I use: pip --version

I'm not sure what's going on. Everything else installed fine but I'm stuck here. If anyone has better instructions, please post. 
Thanks

Comment: What version of Python are you using? What operating system? Were you able to run `gcloud init` properly?

Comment: I have MACOS and Python 2.7. Yes, I was able to do all the steps before and run gloud init.

Comment: You might have multiple installations of Python or pip. If you have Homebrew, I'd try `brew install python`, `brew linkapps python`, and then `brew link --overwrite python`.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. This is running in the virtualenv and the point is not to touch the other configurations.

Comment: Hmm. Are you creating your virtualenv environment in a directory containing spaces?

Comment: Yes. Is that a prohibited?

Comment: It's not "prohibited," but it is the cause of your problem. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

My python Anaconda installation could be causing the pip error. The trick is to do steps 5-6 of the [aforementioned guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/command-line) using the conda virtualenv. Follow the instructions to tensorflow with conda [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac). Then install the google cloud sdk with conda [with](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/google-cloud-sdk):

```
conda install -c bioconda google-cloud-sdk
```

After that, activate the container with:

```
source activate tensorflow
```

and then:

```
gcloud init
```