# setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am going through the Google Cloud Platform's [Python Bookshelf App Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app) and I am at the step of [starting up my virtualenv](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) where I am stuck.

Running `virtualenv -p python3 env` produces this error:

```
⇒  virtualenv -p python3 env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/puoygae/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/puoygae/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/puoygae/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/puoygae/Lab/ga...data/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/b3/0a106dfaf7f48aef638da80b32608617cc8de4b24a22c8cd3759c32e5d30/setuptools-41.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/07/f7d7ced2f97ca3098c16565efbe6b15fafcba53e8d9bdb431e09140514b0/pip-19.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 343, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 321, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/Users/puoygae/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy_install.py'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2327, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/puoygae/Lab/ga...data/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

I had followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup) to set up my python development environment. I searched the internet for a solution but I haven't had luck getting pass this step.

What is causing the issue and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** Running it with sudo produces the following error:

```
⇒  sudo virtualenv -p python3 env
Password:
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/myUserName/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/myUserName/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/bin/python (you must use /Users/myUserName/Lab/gae-bookshelf-app-python-flexible-experiment/getting-started-python/2-structured-data/env/bin/python3)
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/myUserName/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/myUserName/Lab/ga...data/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel:
  The directory '/Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/b3/0a106dfaf7f48aef638da80b32608617cc8de4b24a22c8cd3759c32e5d30/setuptools-41.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (576kB)
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/07/f7d7ced2f97ca3098c16565efbe6b15fafcba53e8d9bdb431e09140514b0/pip-19.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 476, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 353, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 257, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 231, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 388, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2327, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/myUserName/Lab/ga...data/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Comment: permission denied. Do it with sudo

Comment: @PySaad Thanks for the suggestion. Running it with `sudo` produces a different error. Please see edited question.

Comment: The program `/bin/easy_install` is not running. Error ` (permissions problem). This probably causing the last error (error 2) which is a missing file.  I think the real issue is that you are using Python 2 to setup Python 3 which is breaking everything. Setup Python 3 in your path, then use virtualenv to setup your local environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley Python3 is in inside $PATH as the first item (`/Users/myUserName/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`). Even though I am expliciting calling the use of python3 (`virtualenv -p python3 env`), any idea why python2 is involved? I am using MaxOS so perhaps the built-in python2 is being used? I would appreciate any tip, thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling virtualenv? : `pip uninstall virtualenv` and then `pip install virtualenv` or `easy_install virtualenv`. If these steps does not solve the issue, can you provide us with the virtualenv version by running `virtualenv --version`?

Comment: I solved this by creating a new User account on my MacOS and installed python separately. It seems like my environment in my Admin account is quite convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

@puoygae fixed his issue by creating a new User account on his MacOS and installed python separately. The environment in his Admin account was convoluted.

Other fixes to this known issue can be :

- Removing all virtualenv* things in
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and reinstalling it as per
  this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/876).
- Uninstall any setuptools and wheels from pip. Also uninstall them
  from the `apt-get remove wheel setuptools virutalenv`(if they exist,
  In some cases wheels and setuptools both can exist and may conflict
  with each other from pip and apt-get installations) > Download fresh
  setuptools-35.0.2 from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) and virutalenv-15.1.0 from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
  Install both the tools freshly.
- Follow the instructions on updating openSSL [here](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401) and then try
  setting up a virtual environment using pip install.
- Could try to open the system terminal and type pip install
  virtualenv. Restart IDE.
- Try installing pysocks - sudo pip install pysocks Use - unset
  all_proxy Retry
- Also you can try upgrading to platformio-ide 2.1.5
- "setenv all_proxy https://proxy_here:port_here/". Solves the proxy
  problem for not only this setup but for all installations.
- Also have a look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv/) fixes for the
  same issue.

Reference Links :

https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide/issues/1245
https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/876

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.

My pip was looking at a different repo, the one I created using AWS's CodeArtifact, which needs login and credentials.
In my case, all I needed to do was erase this file `~/.config/pip/pip.config`