# Flask run “command not found”

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I've got `pip` installed, I've got `flask` installed. I've even managed to deploy the thing to Heroku and it's been working great.

Today, I wanted to run the dev server and suddenly, the command `flask run` can't be found. I must have made some changes to it but I'm thrown how I can see both `pip` and `flask`, yet it seems to not exists when I run the commands.

Does anything look broken here?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, try to delete the `venv` folder and recreate the `venv`.

Maybe try moving the folder to a shorter path (absolute), or moving it to a path without spaces (absolute).

Also: [Can't install via pip with Virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv/41355718)